# in eclipse 3.61 getting error when trying to install google WindowMaker via updatesite

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

im trying to install the google GUI builder "Window maker pro"
im using eclipse Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705.
but im getting this error when trying to install via updatesite:

> Software being installed:
>   WindowBuilder Core
>   0.9.0.r36x201102111130 (org.eclipse.wb.core.feature.feature.group
>   0.9.0.r36x201102111130)   Missing requirement: WindowBuilder Core
>   0.9.0.r36x201102111130 (org.eclipse.wb.core.feature.feature.group
>   0.9.0.r36x201102111130) requires 'org.eclipse.pde.feature.group 3.2.0'
>   but it could not be found

what the hell is : org.eclipse.pde.feature.group 3.2.0

Comment: Which eclipse package did you download originally?

Comment: it was eclipse for c++ , then added for javaEE and java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think in that case the PDE (plugin development environment) is missing, Window Maker probably depends on this for its SWT/JFace part.

You could try adding the full PDE package from the eclipse software site directly. In Eclipse go to:
Help - Install new software - Work with: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios

After a long update, a "General Purpose" node should appear in the list. After expanding the node, you should see "Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment". Try installing this first and then Window Maker Pro.

Alternatively, you can always use Yoxos - http://ondemand.yoxos.com/geteclipse/start - to fully customise your Eclipse installation.